# Netbeans API: How to save a file, or all files in the current project?

Tags: java, netbeans, save, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins

I'm developing a plugin module for Netbeans using the provided API in order to provide support for a new programming language.

I've created an Action in the Context Menu, using the MIME-type defined in a File Type.

I looking for a method to save the file that's being selected. Preferably only if it's changed.

Also is it possible to save all the changes in all the files of the project?

Part of my code from the Action Listener class:

```
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        FileObject f = context.getPrimaryFile();
        String path = f.getPath();     
        String name = f.getName();

        //Save file here

        ExecutionDescriptor descriptor = new ExecutionDescriptor()
                .controllable(true)
                .frontWindow(true)
                .preExecution(before)
                .postExecution(after);
        ExecutionService exeService = ExecutionService.newService(
                new ProcessLaunch(cmdLine),
                descriptor, "Run " + name);
        Future<Integer> exitCode = exeService.run();

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

`LifecycleManager.getDefault().saveAll();`

This will save all the objects in your project.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
FileObject f = ...
DataObject data = DataObject.find(f);
EditorCookie cookie = data.getLookup().lookup(EditorCookie.class);
cookie.saveDocument();
```

Comment: Providing code is nice and all but nobody learns anything from it; you should explain the thought process behind it.

Comment: what thought process should be behind that?
He has a FileObject and wants to save. The save method is in the EditorCookie, so he needs one.
DataObject.find(), getLookup() and lookup() are all just getter methods - nothing fancy involved there.
FileObject, DataObject and Lookup are all NetBeans concepts, that are  too complex to explain here.